# JQuery selectors seems to not work except when selecting document

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to learn how to use jQuery AJAX with PHP.

My problem is that whenever I am selecting any other element besides `document`, nothing seems to work. What I want to is to simply prevent the page from loading after pressing the submit button to no avail.

I've tried using jQuery instead of $, and still no luck.

I am honestly not sure what I am doing, and I've tried searching for hours for the solution for this one.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("p").click(function() { 
         alert('test');
    });
    $("form").submit(function() { 
         alert('test');
         return false;
    });
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        Inputs:<br />
        <textarea rows="15" cols="60" id="input" name="input">Some text...
        </textarea><br /><br />
        Start:
        <input type="text" id="start" name="start" />
        End:
        <input type="text" id="end" name="end" /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="output">Output: Some Random Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select elements before they have loaded. Use the [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to run your code once the document has been loaded.

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $("p").click(function() { 
             alert('test');
        });
        $("form").submit(function() { 
             alert('test');
             return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your JavaScript is running before the rest of the page has loaded. To fix it, move your script to the bottom of the page (before the closing `</body>` tag), or bind an event handler to the DOM ready event with the jQuery [`.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code in here
});

//or, use the shorthand form:

$(function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

---

*Side note*

> I've tried using jQuery instead of $, and still no luck.

There is no difference between `jQuery` and `$`. Both are just identifiers that hold a reference to the same object. It's usually easier to use `$` (just because it's shorter) unless you're using another library in addition to jQuery that requires that identifier too (such as PrototypeJS), in which case you can tell jQuery to relinquish control of the `$` identifier with the `.noConflict()` method.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Might I ask why selecting document still worked even if it was not ready?

Comment: @Chad - No problem, glad I could help :) You can select the `document` because it's created first, before the markup is parsed and rendered. This makes sense, because it's kind of the root object of any page.